# as.character(parse(text = "\"A\"")) and keep literal quotes (base R only)

Tags: r

I want to quickly tidy R code and keep any literal quotes if they exist. I tried `as.character(parse(text = "  \"A\" # remove this comment"))`, but that returns `"A"`, not the desired `"\"A\""`. I know about `formatR::tidy_source()`, but I am wondering if there is a slick solution in base R.

Comment: Try `x <- '"A"'`.

Comment: This is a very minimal example, but in the actual use case, the text/code is arbitrary, and I do not have control over how it is quoted.

Comment: `paste(scan(text = "  \"A\" # remove this comment", what = character(), comment.char = '#', quote = NULL), collapse = ' ')`

Comment: `x <- c("A", "B"); paste('"', x, '"')`.